# Excel Pivot Export from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple functions that generate multiple data frames of different lengths, I am aiming to consolidate all of them in one place and later pivot it out and export to Excel, here is an example of three different output data frames from three functions.

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'Header':['L1','L2','L3'], 'Val1':[float(100),float(200),float(300)],
         'Val2':[float(400),float(500),float(600)], 'Val3': 
         [float(700),float(800),float(900)]}
data1_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

# Inside loop it'll create two more such outputs but with different values but with the same labels.

data2 = {'Header':['L5','L6'], 'Val5':[float(1000),float(1100)],
         'Val6':[float(1300),float(1400)]}
data2_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

data3 = {'Header':['L7','L8','L9','L10'], 'Val7':[float(1900),float(2000),float(2100),float(2200)],
         'Val8':[float(2900),float(2300),float(2400),float(2800)], 'Val9': 
         [float(3500),float(3600),float(3700),float(3900)]}
data3_summary = pd.DataFrame(data=data3)
```

There are different 'Headers' in all three outputs, similarly, there are different labels 'Val1' to 'Val9' and there are corresponding values against each of them, If we output everything in a sheet (i.e.,data1_summary,data2_summary,data3_summary) it'll be like a grid and later we can perform pivot on that data.

The expected output is as follows.

|  | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | Val5 | Val6 | Val7 | Val8 | Val9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 100 | 400 | 700 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L2 | 200 | 500 | 800 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L3 | 300 | 600 | 900 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1000 | 1300 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1100 | 1400 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| L7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1900 | 2900 | 3500 |
| L8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2000 | 2300 | 3600 |
| L9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2100 | 2400 | 3700 |
| L10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2200 | 2800 | 3900 |

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Comment: Some problem with solution?

Comment: @jezrael I have updated the question with the Expected solution, I hope you will be able to help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need remove `Header` columns and then create default columns names use:

```
dfs = [data1_summary,data2_summary,data3_summary]
df = pd.concat(x.drop('Header', axis=1)
               set_axis(range(len(x.columns)-1), axis=1) for x in dfs)

print (df)
        0       1       2
0   100.0   400.0   700.0
1   200.0   500.0   800.0
2   300.0   600.0   900.0
0  1000.0  1300.0     NaN
1  1100.0  1400.0     NaN
0  1900.0  2900.0  3500.0
1  2000.0  2300.0  3600.0
2  2100.0  2400.0  3700.0
3  2200.0  2800.0  3900.0
```

Or if need only create default columns names use:

```
dfs = [data1_summary,data2_summary,data3_summary]
df = pd.concat(x.set_axis(range(len(x.columns)), axis=1) for x in dfs)

print (df)
     0       1       2       3
0   L1   100.0   400.0   700.0
1   L2   200.0   500.0   800.0
2   L3   300.0   600.0   900.0
0   L5  1000.0  1300.0     NaN
1   L6  1100.0  1400.0     NaN
0   L7  1900.0  2900.0  3500.0
1   L8  2000.0  2300.0  3600.0
2   L9  2100.0  2400.0  3700.0
3  L10  2200.0  2800.0  3900.0
```

EDIT: You can use list comprehension with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
dfs = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]

df = (pd.concat((x.set_index('Header') for x in dfs), axis=1)
        .rename_axis(None)
        .fillna(0, downcast='int'))

print (df)
     Val1  Val2  Val3  Val5  Val6  Val7  Val8  Val9
L1    100   400   700     0     0     0     0     0
L2    200   500   800     0     0     0     0     0
L3    300   600   900     0     0     0     0     0
L5      0     0     0  1000  1300     0     0     0
L6      0     0     0  1100  1400     0     0     0
L7      0     0     0     0     0  1900  2900  3500
L8      0     0     0     0     0  2000  2300  3600
L9      0     0     0     0     0  2100  2400  3700
L10     0     0     0     0     0  2200  2800  3900
```

If possible duplicates in `Header`s is possible aggregate `sum` per `Header`s:

```
dfs = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]

df = (pd.concat((x.set_index('Header') for x in dfs), axis=1)
        .groupby('Header', sort=False)
        .sum()
        .reset_index())

print (df)
  Header   Val1   Val2   Val3    Val5    Val6    Val7    Val8    Val9
0     L1  100.0  400.0  700.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1     L2  200.0  500.0  800.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2     L3  300.0  600.0  900.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
3     L5    0.0    0.0    0.0  1000.0  1300.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
4     L6    0.0    0.0    0.0  1100.0  1400.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
5     L7    0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0  1900.0  2900.0  3500.0
6     L8    0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0  2000.0  2300.0  3600.0
7     L9    0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0  2100.0  2400.0  3700.0
8    L10    0.0    0.0    0.0     0.0     0.0  2200.0  2800.0  3900.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) on `axis=1` after setting `id` as index:

```
dfs = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]

out = (pd.concat((d.set_index('Header') for d in dfs), axis=1)
         .rename_axis(None)
      )
```

Or using [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html) (or any other aggregation function depending on how you want to handle potential duplicates, e.g. [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sum.html) of you rather want to add values with the same Header and Val):

```
dfs = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]

out = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Header', sort=False).first().rename_axis(None)

# for a sum
out = pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Header', sort=False).sum().rename_axis(None)
```

Output:

```
      Val1   Val2   Val3    Val5    Val6    Val7    Val8    Val9
L1   100.0  400.0  700.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
L2   200.0  500.0  800.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
L3   300.0  600.0  900.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
L5     NaN    NaN    NaN  1000.0  1300.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
L6     NaN    NaN    NaN  1100.0  1400.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
L7     NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  1900.0  2900.0  3500.0
L8     NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  2000.0  2300.0  3600.0
L9     NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  2100.0  2400.0  3700.0
L10    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN  2200.0  2800.0  3900.0
```

If you rather want to keep `Header` as column:

```
dfs = [data1_summary, data2_summary, data3_summary]

out = (pd.concat((d.set_index('Header') for d in dfs), axis=1)
         .reset_index()
      )

# or
pd.concat(dfs).groupby('Header', as_index=False, sort=False).first()
```